# How can i add a number to an edit text in android studio

Tags: java, android

So I have an app where I have an edit text to shows how much coins they have (the default is already set to 20) I want after for example an action happens it adds 1 coin to the coins , for example the user has 20 coins by default after doing something in the app it adds 1 coin to the total , I tried this :

```
mCoins.setText(mCoins.getText().toString() + 1);
```

but instead of the coins turning to 21 it turns to 201 , instead of adding the sum of 1 and 20 it just adds 1 beside the 20 , is there anyway i could fix this ? and thanks

Comment: + operator with String will concat the operands . Make it integer .

Comment: can you explain more please or give me the code ? i'm really bad at programming and thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is concatenating both strings:
which results in "20"+"1" = "201"

What you need to do is get int value, add 1 and then set text:
mCoins.setText(Integer.parseInt(mCoins.getText().toString()) + 1);

which will result in
20+1 = 21